# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'GlobalWorkerOptions' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, pdf.js

I am making a whiteboard based on the HTML5 canvas. I have add many features such as upload image, pencil, eraser, shapes and so on. For the upload pdf functionality I am using pdf.js to upload the pdf file to the canvas. I am getting the file using an input tag. While trying to render the pdf to the canvas I am getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'GlobalWorkerOptions' of undefined at FileReader.reader.onloadend ". Here is my HTML

```
    <script src="//mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.js"></script>
```

,input tag

```
<div class="tool" data-upload-type="pdf" title="Uplaod PDF File">
    <input type="file" id="file" accept="application/pdf">
    <label for="file">
    <img src="images/upload_pdf_icon.png">
    </label>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
document.querySelectorAll("[data-upload-type").forEach(
    upload_type => {
        upload_type.addEventListener("click", e => {
            let file_type = upload_type.getAttribute("data-upload-type");
            let file_object = document.getElementById("file");

            if(file_type == "pdf"){
                file_object.addEventListener("change", function(e){
                    if(e.target.files){
                        let file = e.target.files[0];
                        pixieBoard.uploadPdf(file);
                }});
              }
        });
    })
```

and the uploadPdf function

```
uploadPdf(file){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var self = this;
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onloadend = function(event) {
        var pdfjsLib = window['pdfjs-dist/build/pdf'];
        pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.2.2/pdf.worker.js';
        var loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument({url:event.target.result})
        loadingTask.promise.then(function(pdf) {
            pdf.getPage(1).then(function(page) {
                var scale = 0.75;
                var viewport = page.getViewport({scale: scale});
                var renderContext = {
                    canvasContext: self.context,
                    viewport: viewport
                };
                page.render(renderContext);
                self.context.clearRect(0, 0, self.whiteboard.width, self.whiteboard.height);
                self.context.beginPath();
            })})}   
        }
```

Can someone please help me with solving this issue.